# Why do Facebook followers not shown in Safari & IE8?

Tags: java, html, facebook

We integrated facebook in our web application [Java GWT].

Facebook page followers shown in Mozila firefox 3.07 and Google :)
but not shown in Safari and IE8 :(

we used following script in our Java coding to show facebook page followers[Like]:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'> FB.init('MY_APP_ID');</script> <fb:fan profile_id=\"MY_PAGE_ID\" stream=\"0\" connections=\"10\" logobar=\"0\" width=\"244\" height=\"240\" css='http://127.0.0.1/myWebApplicationName/facebook.css?1'></fb:fan>
```

What's the problem?

What changes will need to fb page followers in all browser?

Is there any solution to Show facebook page followers to All browser?

Thank you in Adavance !!!

Comment: Actually, your "Java coding" is not Java, but JavaScript. Apart from the name, they have nothing in common.

Comment: Hello frined [Venemo]
we used above javascript in java code using 

VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();

mainPanel.getElement().setInnerHTML("Above_JavaScript");

plz, provide any Good answer

Answer (score 0):

You have rogue spaces (may not actually be the problem, but should be sorted anyway).

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  FB.init('MY_APP_ID'); 
</script>
<fb:fan profile_id=\"MY_PAGE_ID\" stream=\"0\" connections=\"10\" logobar=\"0\" width=\"244\" height=\"240\" css='http://127.0.0.1/myWebApplicationName/facebook.css?1'></fb:fan>
```

**Also, make sure you have replaced "MY_PAGE_ID" and "MY_APP_ID" with the proper variables.**

Comment: Hello friend

Thank you for Replay

I removed un-necessary space,but it won't work

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US'></script><script type='text/javascript'>FB.init('MY_APP_ID');</script><fb:fan profile_id=\"MY_PAGE_ID\" stream=\"0\" connections=\"10\" logobar=\"0\" width=\"244\" height=\"240\" css='http://127.0.0.1/myWebApplicationName/facebook.css?1'></fb:fan>

web newly used above code still won't work

please provide any other solution!!
Hope-for best co-operation from your side

Comment: I have added a new section to my answer.

Comment: Both page_id & app_id are correct. FB_LIKE box display in Mozila.
But not display in any other browser.
In this script no need to apply app_id just mention FB.init("")

This testfb.html is opens in mozila only & How to dispay in other browser 
for confirmation I'm sending you testfb.html file content :

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US"></script><script type="text/javascript">FB.init("");</script>

<fb:fan profile_id="113106068709539" stream="0" connections="10" logobar="0" width="250" height="300"></fb:fan>

Comment: :) Hope for Best co-operation from your side Sir :).

Comment: I'm afraid I am stumped - hopefully someone else can help you - apologies my good man.

Comment: Hello Neurofluxation :)
Can you suggest any person? who solve my problem :(?